# How to execute a query activity once contacts enter the journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a Journey which Salesforce contacts as entry point. Once they enter the journey i have a 1 hr wait time. Before sending an email i need to run the query activity as i am getting some signature information from DE.

Is there any way in Automation studio to check if a new rows added to Journey builder Data extensions or Salesforce Sync DE i can run the query activity as i am combining multiple info from Salesforce sync objects(sync period 15 min) and Local DE.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Why don't you search for the information you need in the DE using AMPScript or SSJS.

Comment: The information i need is a combination of salesforce sync data and DE data as we don't have all the info in salesforce so i wrote a join query activity.